# ServiceStack.Text JsConfig.IncludePublicFields = true doesn't work with DataContracts

Tags: c#, json, servicestack, deserialization, datacontract

I set `ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.IncludePublicFields = true;` in `AppHost.Configure` but public fields are still not deserializing in JSON format.
Here is a simplified example:

```
[DataContract(Name = "RspItems")]
public class RspItems<T1>
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ItemCount { get { return Items == null ? 0 : Items.Count; } set { } }
    [DataMember]
    public IList<T1> Items;
    public void SetItems(T1 item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            Items = new List<T1>(1);
            Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    public void SetItems(IList<T1> items)
    {
        Items = items;
    }
}
[DataContract(Name="UserInfo")]
public class UserInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    public int UserID;
    [DataMember]
    public string LoginName;
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName;
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName;
    [DataMember]
    public string Comment;
}
public class UserInfoReq<T> : IReturn<RspItems<T>>
{
    public int? UserID { get; set; }
}
[Route("/app/user/list", "GET")]
public class UserInfoGetReq : UserInfoReq<UserInfo> { }

public class UserList : Service
{
    public RspItems<UserInfo> Get(UserInfoGetReq req)
    {
        RspItems<UserInfo> rsp = new RspItems<UserInfo>();
        UserInfo u = new UserInfo();
        u.UserID = 3418;
        u.LoginName = "jsmith";
        u.FirstName = "John";
        u.LastName = "Smith";
        u.Comment = req.UserID.HasValue ? req.UserID.ToString() : "NULL";
        rsp.SetItems(u);
        return rsp;
    }
}
```

The above example does not deserialize the response object in JSON format, although it works in XML format.
But inexplicably, if I remove the `DataContract` attributes on the classes, JSON format works.
Is this a bug?

Also, in the request DTO above, if I make `UserID` a simple public field (instead of being a property), then it is not deserialized from the querystring. Why?

Why does ServiceStack not include public fields by default anyway? Aren't DTOs supposed to be just "flat" structures used as a container for serializing/deserializing inputs and outputs (ie: the simpler, the better)? Public fields are also smaller and faster (no generated hidden private fields and getter/setter functions).

Note: Please don't suggest to just turn all public fields into properties because there are already tons of serialization structures that exist in the project. With many coming from different teams.